# Partial results on Weka attribute selection

Tags: weka, pca

When I run PCA in WEKA GUI using "Select Attribute", I dont get a complete results instead a partial results with dots at the end.

***0.8205   1 -0.493Capacity at 10th Cycle-0.483Capacity at 5th Cycle-0.473Capacity at 50th Cycle-0.261S [M]in Electrolyte -0.256C wt %...***

Is there any way to solve this particular issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, a maximum of 5 attribute names are included in the generated names.

If you want *all* of them, use `-1` for the `-A` option (or `maximumAttributeNames` property in the GOE).

Comment: Also, when I perform percentage split as my "Test options" and save my results, Only the results from test sets are saved and not the trained dataset. Is there any possibility to rectify this obtain both the trained and test sets when run on GUI platform?

Comment: I don't think so that you can do that with the Explorer, you'd have to run a separate *Evaluate on training set*.